# Cannot copy from pdflatex-created PDF

Tags: pdftex, viewers, copy-paste

When I create a PDF using `pdflatex`, I can neither copy from it nor search across lines. Is there any way to make these things possible? I tried `cmap`, but it doesn't help at all.

Here is an example document containing the preamble I typically use, minus the stuff that I'm certain that it isn't related to this problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{cmap}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am able to copy from a PDF a created using your example, using either sumatraPDF or Adobe Reader as the PDF viewer. Maybe your PDF viewer is broken?

Comment: Indeed, it works with Sumatra but not with Evince. I'm uninstalling that piece of crap right now. Ridiculous.

Comment: Then we probably should close this question: it is about Evince bugs rather than TeX problems...